# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS getting into emergency mode and then exiting I can use the system

Tags: boot, 18.04, mode

I have a Dell Laptop on which I had factory-installed Ubuntu and at the time of writing this I am using **Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS**. From past 2 days all of a sudden when I restart my laptop it takes quite an amount of time to boot and then goes into emergency mode. On the emergency mode screen when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> the `root` user prompt appears and when I type `exit` **fortunately** I can see the login screen and can get into the system and start using it.

I explored various resources I found related to this problem and most of them says that such thing happens when the file system is corrupted or caused by dual boot or a new partition is created or there is some problem in `/etc/fstab`. Dual boot and New partition creation definitely not is applicable in my case. If the file system is corrupted sorry to say that I have no idea on how to diagnose it. If there are issues in `/etc/fstab` then I have not touched it for years.

I checked `journalctl -xb` and extracted logs which were referred to the in most of the related resources I found on web. Below is the output with different grep terms. Since the output of that command was very long I thought it wouldn't be useful to post it all here. *Also from the emergency mode terminal itself how to grab that whole output so that I can paste it here in code format I don't know as I am not an expert on using the terminal. The only way I could think of is taking a photo of the screen using my mobile camera.* Considering this I hope that what I have provided below will help anybody who can help me out in this matter. And if more information is needed then please let me know and I will try to furnish it.

Log-1:

```
jignesh@jignesh-Latitude-7290:~$ journalctl -xb | grep "Timed out"
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-bc558793\x2d243d\x2d4a5e\x2d9369\x2d5c7b3b339c6f.device.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-345e070f\x2d3d96\x2d40a9\x2d8774\x2df7eeb8d4a958.device.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.device.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.device.
```

Log-2:

```
jignesh@jignesh-Latitude-7290:~$ journalctl -xb | grep "timed out"
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-bc558793\x2d243d\x2d4a5e\x2d9369\x2d5c7b3b339c6f.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-bc558793\x2d243d\x2d4a5e\x2d9369\x2d5c7b3b339c6f.device/start timed out.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-345e070f\x2d3d96\x2d40a9\x2d8774\x2df7eeb8d4a958.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-345e070f\x2d3d96\x2d40a9\x2d8774\x2df7eeb8d4a958.device/start timed out.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.device/start timed out.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.device/start timed out.
```

Log-3:

```
jignesh@jignesh-Latitude-7290:~$ journalctl -xb | grep "dependency"
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: mnt-jchamber.mount: Job mnt-jchamber.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dns-clean.service: Job dns-clean.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: home.mount: Job home.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-345e070f\x2d3d96\x2d40a9\x2d8774\x2df7eeb8d4a958.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-345e070f\x2d3d96\x2d40a9\x2d8774\x2df7eeb8d4a958.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: boot-efi.mount: Job boot-efi.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: swap.target: Job swap.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.swap: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

Log-4 (extract of more details for timed out entries)

```
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-bc558793\x2d243d\x2d4a5e\x2d9369\x2d5c7b3b339c6f.de
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-bc558793\x2d243d\x2d4a5e\x2d9369\x2d5c7b3b339c6f.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-bc558793\x2d243d\x2d4a5e\x2d9369\x2d5c7b3b339c6f.device has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt/jchamber.
-- Subject: Unit mnt-jchamber.mount has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt/jchamber.
-- Subject: Unit mnt-jchamber.mount has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mnt-jchamber.mount has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: mnt-jchamber.mount: Job mnt-jchamber.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-bc558793\x2d243d\x2d4a5e\x2d9369\x2d5c7b3b339c6f.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-345e070f\x2d3d96\x2d40a9\x2d8774\x2df7eeb8d4a958.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-345e070f\x2d3d96\x2d40a9\x2d8774\x2df7eeb8d4a958.de
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-345e070f\x2d3d96\x2d40a9\x2d8774\x2df7eeb8d4a958.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-345e070f\x2d3d96\x2d40a9\x2d8774\x2df7eeb8d4a958.device has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/345e070f-3d96-40a9-8774-f7eeb8d4a958.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-345e070f\x2d3d96\x2d40a9\x2d8774\x2df7eeb8d4a958.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-345e070f\x2d3d96\x2d40a9\x2d8774\x2df7eeb8d4a958.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /home.
-- Subject: Unit home.mount has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit home.mount has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
-- Subject: Unit local-fs.target has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit local-fs.target has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up.
-- Subject: Unit dns-clean.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dns-clean.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dns-clean.service: Job dns-clean.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: home.mount: Job home.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-345e070f\x2d3d96\x2d40a9\x2d8774\x2df7eeb8d4a958.service: Job syste
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-345e070f\x2d3d96\x2d40a9\x2d8774\x2df7eeb8d4a958.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.device/start timed out
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.device.
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.device has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /boot/efi.
-- Subject: Unit boot-efi.mount has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit boot-efi.mount has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: boot-efi.mount: Job boot-efi.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/E2DD-0AED.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.device/start failed wi
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.de
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.device has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/2b1375de-666d-48b3-8a42-154e214abf95.
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.swap has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.swap has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Swap.
-- Subject: Unit swap.target has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit swap.target has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: swap.target: Job swap.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.swap: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Starting Create final runtime dir for shutdown pivot root...
-- Subject: Unit finalrd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit finalrd.service has begun starting up.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Starting Set console font and keymap...
-- Subject: Unit console-setup.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit console-setup.service has begun starting up.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Started Stop ureadahead data collection 45s after completed startup.
-- Subject: Unit ureadahead-stop.timer has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit ureadahead-stop.timer has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Reached target Login Prompts.
-- Subject: Unit getty.target has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit getty.target has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 apparmor[638]:  * Starting AppArmor profiles
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Starting Set console scheme...
-- Subject: Unit setvtrgb.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit setvtrgb.service has begun starting up.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Closed Syslog Socket.
-- Subject: Unit syslog.socket has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit syslog.socket has finished shutting down.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Reached target Timers.
-- Subject: Unit timers.target has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit timers.target has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Reached target Sockets.
-- Subject: Unit sockets.target has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /boot/efi.
-- Subject: Unit boot-efi.mount has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit boot-efi.mount has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: boot-efi.mount: Job boot-efi.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/E2DD-0AED.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2DD\x2d0AED.device/start failed wi
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.de
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.device has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/2b1375de-666d-48b3-8a42-154e214abf95.
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.swap has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.swap has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Swap.
-- Subject: Unit swap.target has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit swap.target has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: swap.target: Job swap.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.swap: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b1375de\x2d666d\x2d48b3\x2d8a42\x2d154e214abf95.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Starting Create final runtime dir for shutdown pivot root...
-- Subject: Unit finalrd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit finalrd.service has begun starting up.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Starting Set console font and keymap...
-- Subject: Unit console-setup.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit console-setup.service has begun starting up.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Started Stop ureadahead data collection 45s after completed startup.
-- Subject: Unit ureadahead-stop.timer has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit ureadahead-stop.timer has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Jun 02 00:18:03 jignesh-Latitude-7290 systemd[1]: Reached target Login Prompts.
-- Subject: Unit getty.target has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit getty.target has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
```

Below is the output of various commands which were asked for by the community in the forums  on which I found questions and answers related to problems similar to I am seeking help about.

`cat /etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=6fe8763a-c5a8-4057-ba4e-a81669304fbf /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=E2DD-0AED  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation
UUID=2b1375de-666d-48b3-8a42-154e214abf95 none            swap    sw              0       0

UUID=345e070f-3d96-40a9-8774-f7eeb8d4a958   /home   ext4     nodev,nosuid   0    2 

UUID=bc558793-243d-4a5e-9369-5c7b3b339c6f /mnt/jchamber auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

`blkid`

```
jignesh@jignesh-Latitude-7290:~$ blkid 
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="ESP" UUID="E2DD-0AED" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="6108d280-31cf-4306-8eb0-0d581ffc507e"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: LABEL="OS" UUID="FCFB-790C" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="6986226f-14b8-4e3f-8728-ee7b279a0222"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="UBUNTU" UUID="6fe8763a-c5a8-4057-ba4e-a81669304fbf" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ec2d94d2-82e7-44c9-b178-04e5a705854b"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: UUID="2b1375de-666d-48b3-8a42-154e214abf95" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="554b71d5-8c3e-4254-9f13-b36b0fa8a70c"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: LABEL="home" UUID="345e070f-3d96-40a9-8774-f7eeb8d4a958" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="92a4ea18-5588-4e49-857e-bde780988581"
/dev/nvme0n1p6: LABEL="jchamber" UUID="bc558793-243d-4a5e-9369-5c7b3b339c6f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8a181965-8f20-4764-83b3-4a94b90acf82"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop21: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop22: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop23: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop24: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop25: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop26: TYPE="squashfs"
```

`lsblk -l`

```
jignesh@jignesh-Latitude-7290:~$ lsblk -l
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0       7:0    0   704K  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/741
loop1       7:1    0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/104
loop2       7:2    0 162.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop3       7:3    0   2.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/920
loop4       7:4    0   704K  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/761
loop5       7:5    0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/102
loop6       7:6    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1494
loop7       7:7    0 248.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
loop8       7:8    0 164.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop9       7:9    0 111.7M  1 loop /snap/core/13250
loop10      7:10   0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2409
loop11      7:11   0  65.2M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
loop12      7:12   0   548K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/106
loop13      7:13   0 110.6M  1 loop /snap/core/12834
loop14      7:14   0   2.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/884
loop15      7:15   0   556K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/112
loop16      7:16   0   2.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/174
loop17      7:17   0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop18      7:18   0 260.7M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32
loop19      7:19   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop20      7:20   0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2344
loop21      7:21   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
loop22      7:22   0   2.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/169
loop23      7:23   0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1434
loop24      7:24   0  81.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop25      7:25   0 242.4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/76
loop26      7:26   0 290.5M  1 loop /snap/photogimp/141
nvme0n1   259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   750M  0 part /boot/efi
nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     5G  0 part 
nvme0n1p3 259:3    0   100G  0 part /
nvme0n1p4 259:4    0  31.8G  0 part [SWAP]
nvme0n1p5 259:5    0   100G  0 part /home
nvme0n1p6 259:6    0 239.5G  0 part /mnt/jchamber
```

`lsblk -d -o name,rota`

```
NAME    ROTA
loop0      1
loop1      1
loop2      1
loop3      1
loop4      1
loop5      1
loop6      1
loop7      1
loop8      1
loop9      1
loop10     1
loop11     1
loop12     1
loop13     1
loop14     1
loop15     1
loop16     1
loop17     1
loop18     1
loop19     1
loop20     1
loop21     1
loop22     1
loop23     1
loop24     1
loop25     1
loop26     1
nvme0n1    0
```

If there is any more information needed please let me know and please help me understand the cause behind this problem and how to fix this permanently.

Thanks.